# CSS media print not working

Tags: javascript, css, printing, media, css-tables

I have a PHP page where I need to put a `print` button. For that I added the Javascript below:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function PrintContent() {
        var DocumentContainer = document.getElementById('prnt');
        var WindowObject = window.open('', 'PrintWindow', 'width=750,height=650,top=50,left=50,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=yes');
        WindowObject.document.writeln(DocumentContainer.innerHTML);
        WindowObject.document.close();
        WindowObject.focus();
        WindowObject.print();
        WindowObject.close();
    }
</script>
```

Now to print the div `prnt` with some css, I added a css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/print.css" media="print">
```

My `print.css` is :

```
.preorder_list 
{
    overflow:hidden;
}
.preorder_list h2
{
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#0e337f;
    font-size:17px;
    margin-top:40px;
}
.preorder_list table
{
    width:750px;
    background:#d5d5d5;
    padding:8px 4px 8px 4px;
     border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border:1px solid #dbdbe2;

}
.preorder_list th
{
    padding:5px;
}
.preorder_list td
{
    text-align:center;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS";
    font-size:15px;
    padding:5px;
}
.preorder_list input[type="text"]
{
    width:50px;
    border:1px solid #b10c04;
    text-align:center;
}

.preorder_list input[type="text"]:focus
{
    color:#1226a1;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.preorder_list.mw
{
    padding:10px 0 10px 20px;
    border:1px solid #e4e3df;

}
.preorder_list.mw:hover
{
    background:#fbfbfa;
}
.preorder_list.sw
{
    margin-top:20px;
    padding:10px 0 10px 20px;
    border:1px solid #e4e3df;
}
.preorder_list h1
{
    color:#1b2d58;
    font-size:18px;
    font-family: "Franklin Gothic Medium", "Franklin Gothic", "ITC Franklin Gothic", Arial, sans-serif;
}
.preorder_list.sw:hover
{
    background:#fbfbfa;
}
```

Where `preorder_list` is the class where all the data resides, the above code is same as the `css` I used to display in . But I am not getting the desired look when I click `Pirnt`, please have a look at the images .[image: Normal view] [image: print preview in one note-same output]

EDIT:

modified javascript code :

```
var DocumentContainer = document.getElementById('prnt');
        var WindowObject = window.open('', 'PrintWindow', 'width=750,height=650,top=50,left=50,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=yes');

        WindowObject.document.writeln('<!DOCTYPE html>');
        WindowObject.document.writeln('<html><head><title></title>');
        WindowObject.document.writeln('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/print.css" media="print">');
        WindowObject.document.writeln('</head><body>');
        WindowObject.document.writeln(DocumentContainer.innerHTML);
        WindowObject.document.writeln('</body></html>');

        WindowObject.document.close();
        WindowObject.focus();
        WindowObject.print();
        WindowObject.close();
```

Comment: How did you add that css? `link` tags should be placed in the `head` section of the page, you haven't created a one to your pop-up window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to create a document using `document.write()`, you have to create the whole document. Try this:

```
WindowObject.document.writeln('<!DOCTYPE html>');
WindowObject.document.writeln('<html><head><title></title>');
WindowObject.document.writeln('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/print.css">');
WindowObject.document.writeln('</head><body>');
WindowObject.document.writeln(DocumentContainer.innerHTML);
WindowObject.document.writeln('</body></html>');
```

Notice, that `media="print"` has an affect only on the print itself, page is not styled on screen. You can omit the attribute, or use `media="all"` instead.

Comment: I modified my javascript coe, same result ! ( I am not used to js codes ! )

Comment: That's my bad... You're using `"media="print"`, it's not used on the screen, you can see the effect only on a printed paper. Just remove the attribute. I've corrected my answer.